eBay errorId 25002 API_INVENTORY "A user error has occurred. Add at least 1 photo."
My code will create an generate authorization code, then exchange for access token, createOrReplaceInventoryItem, getOffer, deleteOffer, createOffer in Sandbox and Production.
But when I try to publishOffer I get 25002 API_INVENTORY error. How to fix?
Response: {"errors":[{"errorId":25002,"domain":"API_INVENTORY","subdomain":"Selling","category":"REQUEST","message":"A user error has occurred. Add at least 1 photo. More photos are better! Show off your item from every angle and zoom in on details.","parameters":[{"name":"0","value":"Add at least 1 photo. More photos are better! Show off your item from every angle and zoom in on details."},{"name":"1","value":"Add at least 1 photo. More photos are better! Show off your item from every angle and zoom in on details."}]}]}
My createOrReplaceInventory data payload has a valid imageURL:
data = {
    # "title": title,
    "product": {
        "isbn": [ISBN],
        "title": eBay_title,
        "description": description,
        "publisher": publisher,
        "edition": edition,
        "aspects": {
            "Language": [language],
            "Book Title": [title],
            "Author": [author],
            "Publisher":[publisher]
        },
        "imageURLs": [
            "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/MtcAAOSwkD1mxd1u/s-l1600.jpg"
            ]
    },
    "condition": condition,
    "conditionDescription": first_paragraph,
    "price": {
        "value": price,
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "packageWeightAndSize": {
        "weight": {
            "value": 6.0,
            "unit": "POUND"
        },
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 12,
            "width": 8,
            "height": 2,
            "unit": "INCH"
        },
        "packageType": "LETTER"
    },
    "itemSpecifics": {
        "nameValueList": [
            {
                "name": "Publisher",
                "value": publisher
            },
            {
                "name": "Author",  # Ensure Author is included here
                "value": author
            }
        ]
    },
    "availability": {
        "shipToLocationAvailability": {
            "quantity": 1,
            "shipToLocationAvailabilityPerShipToLocation": [
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "shippingLocationType": "WAREHOUSE",
                    "merchantLocationKey": merchantLocationKey
                }
            ]
        },
        "pickupAtLocationAvailability": [
            {
                "availabilityType": "IN_STOCK",
                "fulfillmentTime": {
                    "unit": "DAY",
                    "value": 1
                },
                "merchantLocationKey": merchantLocationKey,
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}

My package conforms to publishOffer documentation. And I can publish with a default ISBN "978-3-16-148410-0" in production.

Answer to this problem  "imageURLs" is misspelled should be "imageUrls"
